# Adding username to comment history Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add an initial to my comment history. Like the username will automatically show in the comment so the person do not have to key in manually. It will only display their username of their own.

I have found two guides in this problem. However, it only fits Magento 1.4 and Magento 1.7. After I changed the files in their guide, it is still not working.

Is there a way to make it happen?

[image]

Things I have added to my code:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php

    public function addCommentAction(){
 ......

 // get the login info of current user
 $_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
 $user['email'] = $_user->getUser()->getEmail();
 $user['firstname'] = $_user->getUser()->getFirstname();
 $user['lastname'] = $_user->getUser()->getLastname();

 $order->addStatusHistoryComment($data['comment'] . " Add by {$user['firstname']}", $data['status'])
                ->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible)
                ->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I will edit my question, as those I try is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create simple module and write below code

```
app/code/local/Modulenamespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

<adminhtml>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                        <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment</method>
                    </modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_addComment>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
                <observers>
                    <modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                        <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave</method>
                    </modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_save>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
                <observers>
                    <modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                        <class>SSD_Authorizenetcim_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment</method>
                    </modulenamespace_modulename_unique_node>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_creditmemo_addComment>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>

/app/code/local/Modulenamespace/Modulename/Model/Observer.php

function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderAddComment($observer)
{
    $history = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('history');
    if ($history && isset($history['comment'])) {
        $history['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('history', $history);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoSave($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('creditmemo');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment_text'])) {
        $post['comment_text'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('creditmemo', $post);
    }
}
function controllerActionPredispatchAdminhtmlSalesOrderCreditmemoAddComment($observer)
{
    $post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('comment');
    if ($post && isset($post['comment'])) {
        $post['comment'] .= $this->_getAppend();
        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setPost('comment', $post);
    }
}
protected function _getAppend()
{
    $user     = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
    return "<br/><br/> Posted by: " . $username;
}
```